# Sorting a character vector by numbers in parentheses

Tags: r, string, sorting

These `chr` have to be sorted:

```
files <- c("file (1).csv", "file (2).csv", "file.csv")
```

into:

```
chr [1:3] "file.csv" "file (1).csv" "file (2).csv"
```

So far I have found the [`gtools`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gtools/index.html) package with its `mixedsort` and `mixedorder` function. But they result in:

```
> library("gtools")
> mixedsort(files)    
[1] "file (1).csv" "file (2).csv" "file.csv"
```

Any idea to solve my problem?

Comment: `files[order(nchar(files))]` or something like that maybe?

Comment: that works! thanks, @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `sub`

```
i1 <- as.numeric(gsub("\\D+", "", files))
files[order(!is.na(i1), i1)]
#[1] "file.csv"     "file (1).csv" "file (2).csv"
```

Comment: thanks, a little clunky as a two-liner but it does the job. But I go with the `nchar`solution by @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1